# SSIS OLEDB Command parameters error

Tags: azure, ssis, parameter-passing, oledbcommand

I cant call stored proc from OLEDB Command. Preview gets error:

> [OLE DB Command [420]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An
>   OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is
>   available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0" 
>   Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Syntax error, permission violation,
>   or other nonspecific error".

This sqlcommand works:

```
exec [dbo].[Update_PRODBOM_93Days] '1',5,'se1'.
```

but not this:

```
exec [dbo].[Update_PRODBOM_93Days] ?,?,?
```

My connectionstring is:

```
Data Source=tcp:sld51cxbyz.database.windows.net,1433;User ID=bleetmaa@sld51cxbyz;Initial Catalog=MigrationFromAx;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Persist Security Info=True;Packet Size=0;Application Name=SSIS-DaxPRODtoOEMDW-{2DA081B5-9B6B-403F-B354-F759BEAD952D}DestinationConnectionOLEDB;database=MigrationFromAX;encrypt=True;trustservercertificate=False;connection timeout=30;
```

if I change it to:

```
Data Source=sld51cxbyz.database.windows.net;User ID=bleetmaa@sld51cxbyz;Initial Catalog=MigrationFromAX;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Auto Translate=False;
```

it works.

Does not SQLCLI10 support oledb command?

My database is an Azure database.

My storedprocedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Update_PRODBOM_93Days]
    @PRODID nvarchar(20) 
    ,@PRODSTATUS int
    ,@DATAAREAID nvarchar(4)

AS
BEGIN

    update dbo.PRODBOM_93Days
       SET prodstatus = @PRODSTATUS
    where PRODID = @PRODID and DATAAREAID=@DATAAREAID
END
```

Comment: Use profiler to see what SQL is being sent by SSIS when you run the SQLCommand that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The `?` syntax is for an OLE DB driver. Since, this is Azure, you're using an ADO.NET driver which uses named parameters. Thus

```
exec [dbo].[Update_PRODBOM_93Days] @PRODID, @PRODSTATUS, @DATAAREAID;
```

And then map accordingly except this is an OLE DB Command which only uses an OLE DB Connection Manager...